# Is there a way to get a unified identifier for an iOS contact that works across devices?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

The app I'm creating links to a contact in the user's iOS address book by the contact's unique identifier property.

However, when I run my app on a different device, the contact can't be found in the user's address book despite using iCloud to sync the address book across devices.

It thus seems that the identifier is only unique on that initial device, and gets a new identifier on the other device when sync'd. This appears to be the case whether or not I'm using unified contacts.

Is there any sort of unique identifier that I can use across devices?